# Crawling external data in Coveo

Tags: content-search, coveo

I have a DAM system that houses thousands of PDFs, and I am using Coveo for my site search.  I want to allow these PDFs to be searchable from my site- how can I get them into an index?

The only options I can think of:

- create a data provider and use that for crawling
- duplicate all the media into my media library to be crawled

Is there a better way?

Comment: Syncing/importing your DAM content in the Sitecore content tree would work but @ASURA answer is the simplest way of achieving this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can index external sources like blogs etc using Coveo.

In addition to the items of your Sitecore Content Tree, a search interface built upon Coveo for Sitecore components can return results coming from external systems. (i.e. external to Sitecore). There is a specific section in a Coveo Search component that allows you to specify which sources in Coveo Enterprise Search (CES) should feed the search interface with their indexed items. This example will show you how a search interface could mix search results coming from Sitecore and from external web pages.

You would need appropriate licensing depending on if you are using the cloud version or on-prem.

The content you are trying to index should be browsable like a blog feed etc.

[https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV4/Configuring+an+External+Source](https://developers.coveo.com/x/TYodAg)
[https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV4/Enabling+the+External+Source+in+Sitecore](https://developers.coveo.com/x/UIodAg)
[https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV3/Displaying+External+Content+in+a+Search+Interface](https://developers.coveo.com/x/dQHnAQ)

Comment: If Coveo doesn't have a crawler available for your DAM, you could index it with Coveo Cloud using the Push API if you have an Enterprise Cloud edition license. For on-premises CES, you can create your own connector using the Connectors API if you have an Enterprise edition license.

Comment: On-premises connector API: https://developers.coveo.com/display/Connector/Connector+API+Home
Cloud Push API: https://developers.coveo.com/display/CloudPlatform/Push+API+Usage+Overview